# Separating php from html

Tags: php

I am building a website using php. I would want to separate the php from the html. Smarty engine, I guess does that, but right now its too complicated for me. Looking for a quick fix and easy to learn solution, one which is an accepted standard as well. Anyone helping please.

Comment: *html looks so confusing* - you see the code and its confusing and yet you expect us to help without looking at it... :)  show us relevant part!! :D

Comment: Model-View-Controller pattern

Comment: @NoobEditor sorry can't put out the codes. Edited my question though. Maybe you can help with separating php and html part.

Comment: This won't completely separate your HTML and PHP but you can use a simple static view class. https://github.com/theantichris/Simple-Plugin-Framework/blob/master/src/View.php

Comment: @ManishB What do you mean "can't put out the codes"?

Comment: @GolezTrol this ain't my work laptop so can't put out the codes right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider frameworks or choose a template engine

Answer (score 0):

Use a framework. Depending on your project, either a micro framework like Slim or something more complete like Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

What I sometimes do when writing complex systems with quite much php code is separating it the following way (don't know your exact project, but it might work for you):

You create a php file with all the functions and variables you need. Then, you load every wepgage through the index.php file using .htaccess (so that a user actually always loads the index.php with a query string). Now, you can load the html page using file_get_contents (or similar) into a variable (I call this $body now); this variable can be modified using preg_replace.

An example: In the html file, you write `{title}` instead of `<title>Sometext</title>`
The replacement replaces `{title}` with the code you actually need:

```
$body = str_replace('{title}', $title, $body);
```

When all replacements are done, simply echo `$body`...

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a lot of variables and use them in the template:

In your application:

```
function renderUserInformation($user)
{
  $userName = $user->userName;
  $userFullName = $user->fullName;
  $userAge = $user->age;

  include 'user.tpl.php';
}
```

In user.tpl.php:

```
User name: <?=$username?><br>
Full name: <?=userFullName?><br>
Age: <?=$userAge?>
```

By putting it in a function, you can limit the scope of the variables, so you won't pollute your global scope and/or accidentally overwrite existing variables.
This way, you can just 'prepare' the information needed to display and in a separate php file, all you need to do is output those variables.

Of course, if you must, you can still add more complex PHP code to the template, but try to do it as little as possible.

In the future, you might move this 'render' function to a separate class. In a way, this class is a view (a User View, in this case), and it is one step in creating a MVC structure. (But don't worry about that for now.)

Comment: I should try what you suggested. Thank you GolezTrol.

Answer (score 0):

*Looking for a quick fix and easy to learn solution*

**METHOD 1** (the laziest; yet you preserve highlighting on editors like notepad++)

```
<?php
   // my php
   echo "foo";
   $a = 4;
   // now close the php tag -temporary- 
   // to render some html in the laziest of ways
?>

<!-- my html -->
<div></div>

<?php
   // continue my php code
```

**METHOD 2** (more organized; use template files, after you passed some values on it)

```
<?php
   // my php
   $var1 = "foo";
   $title = "bar";
   $v = array("var1"=>"foo","title"=>"bar");   // preferrable
   include("template.php");
?>
```

*template.php*

```
<?php
   // $var1, $var2 are known, also the array.
?>

<div>
 <span> <?php echo $v["title"]; ?> </span>
</div>
```

Personally, i prefer *method 2* and im using it in my own CMS which uses lots and lots of templates and arrays of data.

Another solution is of course advanced template engines like *Smarty, PHPTemplate* and the likes. You need a lot of time to learn them though and personally i dont like their approach (new language style)

Answer (score -2):

```
function renderUserInformation($user)
{
  $userName = $user->userName;
  $userFullName = $user->fullName;
  $userAge = $user->age;

  include 'user.tpl.php';
}
```